# How can I play PS vita games without PS Vita?

Tags: hardware, ps-vita

Is it possible to play ps vita games *(assume for the sake of the discussion that the games in question are in the compatibility list)* without a PS Vita *(I do own ps3 controllers and physical copy of the games in question)* using only a PS TV ?

Comment: DO NOT UPDATE PAST VERSION 3.60. If you are on a lower ver, search on the web for how to update to 3.60 only. After you do so, go to henkaku.xyz, run the thingie, then follow some tutorial on the web to set AntiBlackList up. This'll allow you to play any game on PSTV. Please note that I'm not responsible if something screws up, this is unofficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the PS TV plays compatible PS vita games, both physical cards and digital downloads, but you will need a TV to connect the PS TV to in order to play them.

Also worth noting is that the PS TV only has 1gb of internal storage so any games which are larger than this will not be playable without a PS vita memory card to expand the storage of the PS TV.

Comment: But only with Henkaku you can get all of them to run.